# 2-line list view not appearing

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a 2-line list view in my activity but I've come across one error that I don't know how to fix. How can I achieve this the AppCompat way? I want to achieve something like in the screenshot attached. My error is on line 52.

```
public class WCLineActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private class Sample {
        private CharSequence title;
        private CharSequence summary;
        private Class<? extends Activity> activityClass;

        public Sample(int titleResId, int summaryResId, Class<? extends Activity> activityClass) {
            this.activityClass = activityClass;
            this.title = getResources().getString(titleResId);
            this.summary = getResources().getString(summaryResId);

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() { return title.toString(); }
        public String getSummary(){ return summary.toString(); }
    }

    private static Sample[] mSamples;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_wc_line);

        // Instantiate the list of samples.
        mSamples = new Sample[]{
                new Sample(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, MainActivity.class),
                new Sample(R.string.waterloo, R.string.zone_1, MainActivity.class)
        };

        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, mSamples));
    }

    static class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView title;
            TextView summary;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater;
        Sample[] mSamples;

        public MyAdapter(Context contexts, Sample[] samples) {
            this.mSamples = samples;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(contexts);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mSamples.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mSamples[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_dualline, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

                viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_title);
                viewHolder.summary = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_subtitle);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            viewHolder.title.setText(mSamples[position].title);
            viewHolder.summary.setText(mSamples[position].getSummary());
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: phone]

[image: error]

[image]

Comment: Can you please post what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with your code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wc_line);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    // Instantiate the list of samples.
    mSamples = new Sample[]{
            new Sample(R.string.bank, R.string.zone_1, MainActivity.class),
            new Sample(R.string.waterloo, R.string.zone_1, MainActivity.class)
    };

    listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, mSamples));
    }
```

Comment: I now have a new problem. When I click a list item it won't take me to the desired page. Please check my latest screenshot and figure out what is wrong and needs changing.

Comment: Try listView.setOnItemClickListener

Comment: your class object is `MainActivity.class`, for both items.

Comment: @Blackbelt change the class for one of the items but still doesn't work

Comment: @Blackbelt, same class object for both items was just added to check for its display. Probably, the owner of this question has to change it

Comment: @Santhana how could you know? Are you developing the application with the OP?

Comment: Add the listener right after you set the adapter. Like this         listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
     int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Click action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
  });

Comment: Does this go after the `onCreate` method or just before the last `}` of it?

Comment: Brilliant - it works! Thanks for the help from both you @Santhana and Blackbelt

Answer (score 2):

`setListAdapter` is a method of `ListActivity`, and it is not available in `Activity`. To overcame it, you can declare a `ListView` in your layout, retrieve the `ListView` with `findViewById` and call `setAdapter`, on that object. E.g.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.id_list);
listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, mSamples));
```